# (EDITED QUES) PHP - Call function within another function

Tags: php, oop, function, get

I have referred to similar questions like this and have done exactly the same way as it should have been but no success. Hence I would appreciate if some one can help me with this

I have a file called view.php which calls a function from a class based on a switch case condition. This function displays the output on the page with few links. When clicked on the link it calls another function which sits in my first function. But obviously when I click my link, nothing happens. That's my code.

**view.php**

```
require_once(..'/functions.php');
$functions = new myfile_functions();
<form method="post" action="view.php"><div>
<p><select name="potentialareas" id="potentialareas">
<option style="font-weight:bold;" value="-1">Select an area to view </option>
<?php 
foreach($accessareas as $accessarea){
    echo "<option value='".$accessarea->id."'>".$accessarea->name. " - " . $accessarea->reporttype.   "</option>"; 
}
?>
</select>
</p>
<p><input name="view" id="view" type="submit" value="View" title="view" /><br /></p>
</div></form>
<div style="border-top:1px dotted #ccc;"></div>
   <?php

if(isset($_POST['view']))
{
    $hierarchyid = $_POST['potentialareas'];
    $reporttype = $DB->get_record_sql("some query");
     switch($reporttype->reporttype)
     {
        case "D Report":
        $functions->getDepartmentReport($hierarchyid);
        break;
        case "S Report":
        $functions->getSectionReport($hierarchyid);
        break;
        case "A Report":
        $functions->getAreaReport($hierarchyid);
        break;
    }   
}
```

**functions.php**

```
class myfile_functions(){

function getDepartmentReport($departmentid)
{
global $USER, $CFG, $DB;

$dname = $DB->get_record_sql("some query");
$output = "<div id='actualreport'><p><b>" . $dname->name. " Department Report</b></p>";
$output .= "<p>Activities started: </p>";
$output .= "<p>Activities Completed: </p></div>";
$output .= "<div id='separator' style='border-top:1px dotted #ccc;'></div>";
$output .= "<div id='listofsections'><p><b><i>Select the following for a more detailed report.</i></b></p>";
$snames = $DB->get_records_sql('some query');
foreach($snames as $sname)
{$output .= "<p>" .$sname->name. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='view.php?section=" .$sname->id. "' name='section'><i>view report</i></a></p>";
}
$output .= "</div>";
if(isset($_GET['section']))
{
       $this->getSectionReport($_GET['section']);
}
echo $output;
 }

 function getSectionReport($sectionid)
 {
global $USER, $CFG, $DB;
$sname = $DB->get_record_sql("some query");
$output = "<div id='actualreport'><p><b>" . $sname->name. " Report</b></p>";
$output .= "<p>Num Users: </p>";
$output .= "<p>Activities Completed: </p></div>";
$output .= "<div id='separator' style='border-top:1px dotted #ccc;'></div>";
$output .= "<div id='listofareas'><p><b><i>Select the following for a more detailed report.</i></b></p>";
$anames = $DB->get_records_sql('some query');
foreach($anames as $aname)
{$output .= "<p>" .$aname->name. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='view.php?area=" .$aname->id. "' name='view' id='view'><i>view report</i></a></p>";
}
$output .= "</div>";
if(isset($_GET['area']))
{
    $areaid = $_GET['area'];
    $this->getAreaReport($areaid);
}
echo $output;
 }
```

Similarly another function calling the above function, n so on.

```
 function getAreaReport($id)
 { .. same content but calling another function...}
```

So when ever I click my `view report` link, I get the id appended id in my querystring, something like

```
 http://mydomain.com/view.php?section=5
```

Ideally the contents of `getSectionReport()` should get printed but its not. Please point out what is it that I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calling `getSectionReport` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, these function are in my class file. `myclass_functions.php`. And I am calling this function based on a switch case condition in one of my other files like this, `$object = new myclass_functions(); $object->getSectionReport($id);`

Comment: And is the function not called, or does the Foreach Loop generates no content?

Comment: if you have a result handler opened and execute another query the previous result handler will be invalid.

Comment: Well I am querying from a database and storing the ids by appending it to the querystring. And my query indeed works because when I click on the link I can see the id of my item that I linked in the querystring. So its just that my function isn't outputting what its supposed to output.

Comment: I have just edited my ques with my skeletal file structure. Please have a look if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your *main* method for displaying everything?  At the moment you have three functions, all of which link to eachother in various ways, but it doesn't look as if you're instantiating anything first.  The PHP is being fed a parameter in your URL, sure, but if a class isn't instantiated and a method declared, how does it know what you want it to do?

For myfile.php, maybe you should do something like:

```
class MyFile
{
   public function other_function()
   {
      // Various stuff
      return 'stuff';
   }
   public function other_other_function()
   {
      // Various other stuff
      return 'other stuff';
   }
   public function page_view($file_id)
   {
      $var = $this->other_function($file_id);
      return $this->other_other_function($var);
   }
}

$class = new MyFile;
echo $class->page_view($_GET['id']);
```

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I should have mentioned this. I have edited my question completely. Please have look.

Answer (score 0):

If the two functions are part of a class (as your comment above hints), then the call should be written as

```
$this->getUserReport($id);
```

Comment: Are they members of the same class?

Comment: Well if u mean are both the functions of the same class , then Yes.

Comment: I have just edited my ques with my skeletal file structure. Please have a look if that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  Looking at the code, my answer and the other answer from @Jamie are absolutely correct on how to call other members from the same class.  There's no doubt about that.  Which means you have three options: (1) the first function, e.g, getSectionReport, is not being called for some reason, (2) the condition that means the second function is called is turning out false, or (3) there's some other error.  I suggest some debugging.  Why not use error_log() to write message to the php_error.log file to find out more about what's going on - e.g., call it from getSectionReport() etc. to check..

Comment: .. what you think is happening is actually happening.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8182/discussion-between-ivn-and-msgmash-com)

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing a sibling function inside the same class, use:

```
class ClassName
{
    public function sibling_function()
    { 
       return 'Hey bro!';
    }
    public function my_function()
    {    
       return $this->sibling_function();
    }
}
```

If not, use the standard:

```
public function my_function()
{ 
    return sibling_function();
}
```

If you're still having trouble, make sure your class is properly instantiated.  There's no point calling another function if you're not even instantiating the class first:

```
$obj = new ClassName;
echo $obj->my_function();
```

Comment: Well the function where I am calling my second function is a resultant of a condition. So say `if` the condition matches `call my 2nd function and output whatever is there in it` else `output my 1st function's data`. Hence I dont think I need to instantiate the class when I am already in that class. Also I am using `$this->secondfunctionname(parameter);` . But still nothing.

Comment: I think we need more information.  Such as: is the class containing these functions in myfile.php.  Also, what errors are you seeing (if any) in the php_error.log (or similar log file)?  Can you add to your question the code that calls getSectionReport?

Comment: I have just edited my ques with my skeletal file structure. Please have a look if that helps.